In my flask app for web Not redirecting to dashboard after login
I am using flask for my webapp using localhost (as folder is in my pc for now) I created a login page besfore my flask app, but not redirecting to dashboard (frontend of flask app) after login. it remains there at login page. there are distribution of my resources I have a templates folder in which i placed login.html, dashboard.html and i have a static folder in which i placed script.js (for password) and style.css. After login i am not redirecting to dashboard. here is code of my flask app
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session, flash
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "your_secret_key"

@app.route('/')
def index():
return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
username = request.form.get('username')
password = request.form.get('password')

if username == 'admin' and password == 'password':
    session['logged_in'] = True
    app.logger.info('Login successful. Redirecting to dashboard...')
    return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
else:
    flash('Invalid username or password. Please try again.', 'error')
    app.logger.warning('Login failed. Invalid username or password.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
if 'logged_in' not in session:
    flash('Please login to access the dashboard.', 'error')
    app.logger.warning('User attempted to access dashboard without login.')
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

app.logger.info('User authenticated. Rendering dashboard...')
return render_template('dashboard')

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)

I tried chatGPt, i am expecting to handle this error and a modified code

Please edit your question and add the HTML code for the form. There is currently no apparent reason for this behavior.

except for the indentation, the code is correct.
try running this code and see what it prints
from flask import (Flask, session,request, flash, redirect,url_for)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "your_secret_key"

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'login'

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form.get('username')
    password = request.form.get('password')
    print(request.content_type)
    print(username)
    print(password)
    if username == 'admin' and password == 'password':
        session['logged_in'] = True
        app.logger.info('Login successful. Redirecting to dashboard...')
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    else:
        flash('Invalid username or password. Please try again.', 'error')
        app.logger.warning('Login failed. Invalid username or password.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
    if 'logged_in' not in session:
        flash('Please login to access the dashboard.', 'error')
        app.logger.warning('User attempted to access dashboard without login.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    app.logger.info('User authenticated. Rendering dashboard...')
    return "dashboard"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


